# TCP SACK PANIC - Kernel vulnerabilities FIXED into Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-176-generic x86_64)?

Tags: kernel, security

I read Ubuntu updates for TCP SACK Panic vulnerabilities article so I updated my Ubuntu server 16.04.6 LTS  getting GNU/Linux 4.4.0-176-generic x86_64. Then i rebooted the server. 
Is this security issues fixed in this kernel version?
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You can check yourself, enter the CVE you're worried about into the web site https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/ and you can see for each release.  fyi: 16.04.6 was released more than a year ago (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) so your mention confuses me unless you no one regularly maintains that server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of relevance is [this Ubuntu Security Notice, USN-4017-1](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2019-June/004960.html) which listed the following versions of the Ubuntu 4.4.0-series Generic Kernel packages as patched for Ubuntu 16.04.  If you are using a version of the linux-image-4.4.0-ABC-generic packages that is higher than this (i.e. the value in ABC is higher than the

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:
  ...
  linux-image-4.4.0-151-generic   4.4.0-151.178
```

Your kernel version is `linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic` which is **newer** than the version that is specified in the 16.04 'fixed' version.  Which means, yes, you are patched.